# How to change a URL (not using fragments) in the address bar without redirecting to a page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

As far as I know it's not possible to change a URL in the address bar without redirecting a page (only updating fragments will work), but in Pinterest.com it seems like only a modal dialog is opened when clicking on a post, and at the same time the URL is updated to ".../post/12356789". I'm curious how do they achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably done using the `history.pushState()` method in "HTML5", which lets you manipulate the browser history (to some extent). Here's an [article](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) detailing how it works.